# Path Variables in Guzzle request

Tags: laravel, postman, guzzle

Best regards, I'm using Guzzle 7 with Laravel 8, and I need to pass a path variable, at least that's how it is called with postman, this my code

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();  
$response = $client->get('xxxxxxxxxxxxxx', [    'params' => ['dni' => 'xxxxxxx'],    'headers' => ['x-api-key' => 'xxxxxxxxx']   ]);
dd($response);
```

but it is as if it does not send anything, I would really appreciate if someone knows how to do this query

Comment: I tried to pass the variable in the body and as a query, even in json format but nothing arrives, it seems that this path variable works only in postman

Answer (score 0):

The guzzle request must look like this:

```
$client->get('http://example.com', ['query' => ['param1' => 'value1']]);
```

This means that you must replace `params` with `query`.
https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/quickstart.html#query-string-parameters

Comment: Disregard the use of Guzzle when you already have the [`Http` facade](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-client) available

Comment: That wasn't the question, the question was why the provided code won't work. In the end the HTTP Facade is a wrapper for guzzle. 
But I also agree that it probably would be better to just use the provided Http facade.

Comment: I know, I am used to seen questions like this, and I still reply with what is best, not what the user is using (if there is something better). Why use Guzzle when you can literally use the `Http` facade? It is way simpler to use and it is 100% testable compared to Guzzle. Authors sometimes ask how to 1+1+1+1+1+1, and I show them how to 5+1, way easier and understandable, just that!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Guzzle, use the native [`Http` facade](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-client) that is available since Laravel 7.x. Using the facade, you have a dedicated section about what you want [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-client#get-request-query-parameters).

So, your code should be like this:

```php
Http::get(
    'YOUR_URL',
    [
        'dni' => 'xxxxx',
    ]
);
```

And if you want to pass more params, just add index and value, and that's it!